# Postfix timeout for incoming mails after few seconds of restart

Tags: ubuntu, timeout, postfix-mta

My Ubuntu server has been working for a long time now. Suddenly it started yesterday to timeout SMTP-connections without any further error. When I restart postfix, I can connect to it (e.g. using telnet on Port 25) for a short time. After that i get

```
Connected to smtp.mydomain.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But the 220 mailserver header is never reached. I checked the postfix processes, they are just at an amount of 13-15.